# Why is this SUM not giving the the expected results?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that works great:

```
SELECT dl.*, d.*, dr.earn_rate
FROM list dl LEFT JOIN rates dr ON dr.id=dl.id AND dr.level = dl.level 
LEFT JOIN widgets d ON d.id=dl.id WHERE user_id=1 AND d.element=3 
ORDER BY dr.earn_rate DESC, dl.name LIMIT 20;
```

I want to quickly get the SUM of all of the earn_rate, and thought I could just put SUM in the SELECT, and leave everything else and it would work.  However, it seems to ignore the LIMIT and sums all of the earn_rate as if there was not a LIMIT.

```
SELECT SUM(dr.earn_rate) FROM list dl 
LEFT JOIN rates dr ON dr.id=dl.id AND dr.level = dl.level 
LEFT JOIN widgets d ON d.id=dl.id WHERE user_id=1 AND d.element=3 
ORDER BY dr.earn_rate DESC, dl.name LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: You are missing group by sum() will return one row unless group by is specified.

Comment: Yes, for the second query, I only need it to return the one row, just the total, so a GROUP BY is not needed.  I just don't understand why it's returning the wrong number.  It's returning the SUM of all 35 rows, not the 20 that I want to limit the results to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LIMIT` clause is applied to the result set, not the intermediate results used to form the results. If you want to sum the top 20 earnings, you need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(earn_rate)
FROM (
    SELECT dr.earn_rate
    FROM list dl
    LEFT JOIN rates dr ON dr.id=dl.id
    AND dr.level = dl.level
    LEFT JOIN widgets d ON d.id=dl.id
    WHERE user_id=1
      AND d.element=3
    ORDER BY dr.earn_rate DESC, dl.name
    LIMIT 20) x
```